# Convergence of a series with a partial sum in it

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I have a series

$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sum_{k=0}^m a_k n^k}{e^n} $

$ m \in N_0, a_1, ..., a_m \in C $

and need to show convergence/divergence. My approach so far has been an ettempt at the Ratio Test, arriving at

$ \frac{e^n \sum_{k=0}^m a_k (n+1)^k}{ee^n \sum_{k=0}^m a_k n^k} $

But now I do not know further, except for an intuition of divergence, because the numerator appears to grow faster. Can someone tell me how to approach this?

Comment: Presumably $m$ is fixed. The ratio test seems like a good idea, and the expression you've obtained is a rational function of $n$ (one polynomial divided by another), since the $e^n$ terms cancel. What is the limit of that rational function of $n$ as $n\to\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at some particular cases (like $a_1=1$, the other ones equals to $0$, or $a_m=1$, and the other terms equal to $0$), we have to deal with series of the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^m e^{-n}$, which are convergent, by the ratio test.

We can reduce to this case, by noticing that
$$
\left\lvert \sum_{k=0}^ma_k n^k\right\vert\leqslant \sum_{k=0}^m\left\lvert a_k \right\vert n^k\leqslant \sum_{k=0}^m\left\lvert a_k \right\vert n^m.
$$